# Difference between simple ajax and :remote => true In Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Actually I have two, three questions but the heart of three question is same as written in Title . But I make my all points clear here in description

Following will be the specification of my question

```
Javascript file path => assets/javascript/
js.erb file path     => views/customers/index.js.erb
view file name       => views/customerS/html.erb
controller name      => customers
action name          => index
```

**point # 1**

If I make ajax call to my customers/index through my javascript file (with the mentioned path) then will it hit the index.js.erb file ?

**point # 2**

can we use js and js.erb file for the same action . what i mean is 'is it possible to send ajax from js file in assets folder and after controller action say index method handle the response in index.js.erb file in view folder ?'

**point # 3**

Say we can handle the response in index.js.erb file then how can / or if we can stop sending back the response / data in js file

if I have missed some more related points then kindly edit the question and place those , so that maximum people can enjoy the knowledge

Also have a look at [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33038370/rendering-partial-view-through-javascript-file-ruby-on-rails/33039416#33039416) and answer if you can

**Update**

I made a small experiment , by keeping the same function as mentioned in the 
  [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33038370/rendering-partial-view-through-javascript-file-ruby-on-rails/33039416#33039416): [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33038370/rendering-partial-view-through-javascript-file-ruby-on-rails/33039416#33039416) , if ajax is sent through js file then js.erb doesn't do any thing but if i made the ajax call using the `:remote => true` , then it hits the js.erb file . Any explaination will be appreciated . For having a look at code sample in js, controller and js.erb kindly see the linked question

Answer (score 1):

I think some language barrier is making it hard to completely understand your question by I'll try an answer.

The flow in Rails for `:remote => true` is this:

click on :remote => true link (`foo`) -> AJAX call is made to the controller requesting it to execute `foo` -> the controller executes the code contained in the `foo` action, it will then look for a file in the same view's folder called `foo.js.erb` and execute that JS -> that code will update the portion of the original HTML page using a file called `foo.html.erb` in the same view's folder.

Any call to a JS function contained in `assets/javascript/` will just execute the JS called, whether it is AJAX or not.

So `assets/javascript/` =  a place to put JS code instead of putting it in `<script>` tags in the HTML file

`:remote => true` =  an AJAX call to a specific controller action that then renders a similarly named .js.erb file and .html.erb file to update the page asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the flow of `assets pipeline` and `js.erb` files is much different . All the thing asked in the question is 
what is difference if ajax is called from assets pipeline and if ajax is called through `:remote => true` . Now the answer is 
,"There is ***almost*** no difference in the sense of functionality but there can be some minor (but in some case) very important differences depending upon our rendering methods and codes in `js` and `js.erb` files" e.g

If I make the ajax from the view i.e by using `:remote=> true` , then It'll simply goto controller action, perform whatever is defined , after that looks into `js.erb` file and finally the `html.erb` file . That's it . Here no assets js is looked for .

Now there is case when we make call from assets javascript , there are two cases for it .

**First case** is that i want to handle the response in the same js file from where the ajax is sending then no worries , control will come back to success function by default , so don't specify the `respond_to` method in the controller's action .

**Second case** is , when we want ajax to be fired from `assets javascript` , but want to handle the response in the `js.erb` file then specify the `respond_to` as below

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.js #{ render 'index.js.erb' }
    format.html
end
```

Now it will hit to js.erb file also . Point to remember is control of program will get back into assets success function also but at this scenario , response will contain the data present in the `js.erb` file instead the data of controller function

> From the above explanation one should remember that assets js is
>   called before getting into rails controller while js.erb functionality
>   is performed after the rails controller has finished it's work .